# Retrieve Guest List from Calendar - Google Apps Script (GAS)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve and report out details of calendar events including all the guests and their email addresses.

I've also tried this and only retrieved one email address (sometimes):

```
function getEmailsFromArray(guestsArray){
var guestEmails = [];
for (var i=0;i<guestsArray.length;i++) {
  guestEmails.push(guestsArray[i].getEmail());
}
return guestEmails; }
```

Here's the code that I'm using now. Help!

```
function export_gsheet(){

var mycal = "myemailaddress@mine.com";
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);

var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("May 02, 2019 00:00:00 PST"), new Date("May 03, 2019 00:00:00 PST"));

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

var header = [["Calendar Address", "Event Title", "Event Description", "Calculated Duration", "Attendees", "Email", "MyStatus", "Created By", "All Day Event", "Recurring Event", "Event Location", "Event Start", "Event End", "Visibility", "Date Created", "Last Updated"]]
var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,1,16);
range.setValues(header);


for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
var row=i+3;
var myformula_placeholder = '';

  var guestList=events[i].getGuestList();   //GET THE EMAIL AND STATUS OF EACH GUEST FOR EACH EVENT 
  for(var d=0; guestList!=null && d<guestList.length; d++)
    {
      var details=[[mycal,events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), myformula_placeholder, guestList[d].getName(), guestList[d].getEmail(), events[i].getMyStatus(), events[i].getCreators(), events[i].isAllDayEvent(), events[i].isRecurringEvent(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), ('' + events[i].getVisibility()), events[i].getDateCreated(), events[i].getLastUpdated()]];
      var range=sheet.getRange(row,1,1,16);
      Logger.log(details);

        var range2 = sheet.getRange(row+d,1,1,16);
        range2.setValues(details);

    }
    row=row+d; // increment row to start the next output after the previous output
}
}
```

The code mostly works but I'm not getting my full guest list for the events and sometimes I'm getting a conference room's name and calendar address instead.

I'm also not getting all of the events in a particular day if the guest list is large for a particular event.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue, for example, when the events.list method of Calendar API is used for your situation, what result will you get? https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the "row" value, the for it's not iterating as you wish. Because each time the inner for finish, the "row" value is set to 3 again. Besides, in the 2nd iteration of the inner for, the "d" value is 0 again so you shouldn't put your "row" value to depend on your "d" value. I fixed and it worked for me with all the events of the day, like this:

```
var row=3;
for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {

var myformula_placeholder = '';

  var guestList=events[i].getGuestList();   //GET THE EMAIL AND STATUS OF EACH GUEST FOR EACH EVENT 
  for(var d=0; guestList!=null && d<guestList.length; d++)
    {      
      var details=[[mycal,events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), myformula_placeholder, guestList[d].getName(), guestList[d].getEmail(), events[i].getMyStatus(), events[i].getCreators(), events[i].isAllDayEvent(), events[i].isRecurringEvent(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), ('' + events[i].getVisibility()), events[i].getDateCreated(), events[i].getLastUpdated()]];
      var range=sheet.getRange(row,1,1,16);
      Logger.log(details);

        var range2 = sheet.getRange(row,1,1,16);
        range2.setValues(details);
        row++; // increment row to start the next output after the previous output
    }   
}
}
```

The only changes are the "row=3" that i put it outside the outer for, and switching "row=row+d" with simply "row++" (and putting it inside the inner for).

About the other issues:

1) The resources(conference rooms) are treated as another guest, so if you don't want it there, you could use an "If" with the resource's email in the condition to avoid this (their emails ends with @resource.calendar.google.com).

2) Review you are using the exact timezone that you want, in this case you are using PST time so the calendar should be in PST time too. (or simply don't put any timezone and it will take the same timezone of the script, which i imagine it's the same as the calendar).

**Edit**

Also you can check out more information about each guest, look the documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-guest

If you want the owner also in the guest list, you have to use `getGuestList(true)` with the boolean inside. Documentation:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getguestlist

Finally, if the names of some of the invitees are not appearing (But it should appear the rest of the information in that row), is probably because you have not been granted permission to see that information (Google doesn't let you know the names of the users that haven't sent you an email).

Comment: Thank you Andres! The problem is with your code I'm only able to get one guest email address. Is there a way to tweak it so that I can get all the email addresses/names of the attendees for a meeting?

Comment: No worries, i've updated the answer, check the code. In my test it's running smoothly, with the "name column" empty for the guests that i haven´t been in contact before but with the rest of the information in the row.